# Counting values on the basis of certain condition in string in PostgreSQL?

Tags: string, postgresql

I have a column **condition** in my table that contains similar text in each row:-

```
Inclusion Criteria:

-  Female

-  > 40 years of age

-  Women who have first-degree relative suffered from breast cancer

-  Women who have first-degree relative suffered from ovarian cancer

-  Family history of male breast cancer

-  Family history of breast cancer (not necessarily first degree relatives) diagnosed before age of 40.

-  Family history of breast cancer (not necessarily first degree relatives) affecting 2 or more family members

-  Personal history of ovarian cancer

-  Personal history of premalignant conditions of breast and ovary

Exclusion Criteria:

     - Women with mammogram within one year
     -  adults aged 50-75
```

I need to find out the count of the inclusion and exclusion criteria in PostgreSQL. Here for example inclusion criteria is 9 and exclusion criteria is 2.

Comment: So this is really a text processing / pattern matching / parsing problem, not database as such.

Comment: In your  example,  entire  text is in one row? or different lines presents here   different rows ?

Comment: @oto : different lines present different rows..i used code array_length (string_to_array (substring(lower(criteria) from 'inclusion(.+)exclusion'), '  -  '), 1) - 1 as cnt  , do we have any better solution?

Comment: @user3222101 - Ok, and do you also have another column (for example `id` or `timestamp` or something like ) which determines order of those rows ?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a stored procedure using PL/pgSQL that will do the parsing and separating. Once you've got it, you can call it on a string or a cell via `SELECT` just like you would any other PostgreSQL function.

If you want to return both values (the inclusions and the exclusions) in one operation it's easiest to make a table that defines their names and types like so:

```
CREATE TABLE condition_counts (
  num_of_inclusions VARCHAR,
  num_of_exclusions VARCHAR
);
```

You can then use it in your stored procedure definition like so:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION parse_conditions(conditions VARCHAR) RETURNS condition_counts AS $$
DECLARE
    condition_matches VARCHAR[2];
    inclusion_count INTEGER;
    exclusion_count INTEGER;
    parsed_conditions condition_counts%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    condition_matches = regexp_matches(conditions,
        E'^Inclusion Criteria:\\s*(.*)\\s*Exclusion Criteria:\\s*(.*)$');
    SELECT array_length(regexp_split_to_array(condition_matches[1], E'\\n\\s*-\\s*'), 1),
           array_length(regexp_split_to_array(condition_matches[2], E'\\n\\s*-\\s*'), 1)
      INTO parsed_conditions.num_of_inclusions, parsed_conditions.num_of_exclusions;
    return parsed_conditions;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

You can now call it on the sample string you provided like so:

```
SELECT * FROM parse_conditions('Inclusion Criteria:

-  Female

-  > 40 years of age

-  Women who have first-degree relative suffered from breast cancer

-  Women who have first-degree relative suffered from ovarian cancer

-  Family history of male breast cancer

-  Family history of breast cancer (not necessarily first degree relatives) diagnosed before age of 40.

-  Family history of breast cancer (not necessarily first degree relatives) affecting 2 or more family members

-  Personal history of ovarian cancer

-  Personal history of premalignant conditions of breast and ovary

Exclusion Criteria:

     - Women with mammogram within one year
     -  adults aged 50-75');
```

and will get the counts of 9 and 2 returned as expected. You can also do a `SELECT parse_conditions(columnname) FROM tablename;` and various other combinations as is normal for PostgreSQL functions.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that all of the above occurs in a single column ?

If so you can use regex pattern matching where you can search from the string 'Inclusion Criteria:' up to the string 'Exclusion Criteria:' and count the rows between.

Regex is great to get your head round. 
[Documentation Here.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html)

Comment: Please see @Feneric comment above.